# How to pass --no-verify-ssl to AWS CLI from Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, boto3

I am new to get AWS CLI working, and finally have my commands working through gitBash with:

```
aws s3 ls --no-verify-ssl
```

I am now trying to run the same commands from Python.
I need to be able to do the following tasks in AWS s3 from Python:

- Copy hundreds of local folders to the s3 bucket.
- Update existing folders on the s3 bucket with changes made on local versions.
- List contents of the s3 bucket.

In reading similar posts here, I see that --no-verify-ssl means there is a bigger problem, however using it is the way our network people have set things up, and I have no control over that. This is the flag they require to be used to allow access to the AWS CLI.

I have tried using boto3 and running the Python command there, but I get an authentication error because I don't know how to pass the --no-verify-ssl flag from Python.

Comment: `client = boto3.client('s3', verify=False)`. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html